# Stuttering at playback

Tags: sound, video, multimedia, midi, playback

I use UbuntuStudio 18.04.1 LTS in an HP 250 G5 notebook (laptop), with Intel Pentium N3710 (4 cores, at 1,6 GHz, 64 bit), 8 GB RAM and a 1 TB har disk drive.

Since I installed the system, I have found a lot of "stuttering" at random time, with audio, video and MIDI music (and I suspect about any other kind of jobs, too).

I'm talking about a very short stop, then the last second is repeated and the playback goes on.

It is absolutely at random time! Could be at starting part, at middle part, or at final part of the piece.

Even more, sometimes I can enjoy a completed piece , whatever its lenght, without any problem!

I don't have any clue about what or where could be the origin of this problem.

I have the same Operating System (with identical software configurations), in other 4 desktop computers (ASUS, Samsung and HSI) and another laptop (Samsung), and this behaviour is only in this HP Device.

Some idea about how to fix this?

Comment: check out this similar issue I have been having since 18.04, I find the lowlatency kernel seems to be confused at times. maybe my solution can help you: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065777/random-temporary-screen-lags-since-upgrade-to-18-04

Comment: obviously for art production you want to keep the low latency kernel, however hopfully something I did to fix my system will help yours.

Comment: I will try it. Just a doubt... Would be there some noticeable difference between the "lowlatency" and the "normal" kernel, at normal situations (audio and video, recording, editing and playback)?

Comment: in 16.04 I ONLY used the low latency kernel and never had any issues.... after the upgrade I had to do a few things (as you saw in my post) to get my system happy and I haven't needed to boot into the LL kernel so I don't know if is still being wonky. I am definitely not the only user that was having lags after the upgrade either...

Comment: I installed the "generic" kernel, and I chose it (from the Grub starting menu), but... When I use the line command "uname -a", I get... Linux jjpg-HP-250-G5-Notebook-PC 4.15.0-34-lowlatency #37-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT Mon Aug 27 17:40:31 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux. In other words, something, inside the system, still chose the lowlatency kernel, despite my decision. What's wrong here???

Comment: I think I found the solution! I just set as unable the internal WiFi adapter of the HP 250 G5 laptop, into the BIOS menu (see: https://support.hp.com/cl-es/document/c05084881, to the specifications of the machine). I did two days ago and... Since that, I don't have any kind of audio and/or video stuttering! So... I think this is some kind of incompatibility between Linux and that hardware piece.