# Random freezes of 18.04.01 with ryzen 2400G

Tags: drivers, crash

I have a Ryzen 2400G and a Asus x370 and run Ubuntu 18.04.1. The virtual machine is enabled in bios but it doesn’t seam to make a difference if it’s switched on or off. And I have two screens connected.
I experience random freezes of the system. It looks like the graphics driver is crashing when playing a video via VLC or HTML5 in firefox. The odd thing is the audio playback resumes but the displays freeze. Very rarely I was able to still move the mouse but mostly that freezes too.

I found this when I searched for the error but the thread seams removed:
https://wyldeplayground.net/ubuntu-18-04-crashes-randomly-on-amd-ryzen-2400-g-with-4-16-12-kernel/

Does anybody have the same problem or might know how to solve it?

Thanks for your help :)

Comment: I have been having similar issues https://askubuntu.com/questions/1065777/random-temporary-screen-lags-since-upgrade-to-18-04 did you upgrade or clean install? I am about to do a clean install to see if it improves performance

Comment: I did a clean install as its a new system. Thanks for the link I'll have a closer look at it, but to me it looks like its a driver problem with the new ryzen 2400G video driver. Lets se if someone else with same hardware config. can share some experiance.