# How to get Ubuntu 20.04 to work?

Tags: 20.04, kubuntu, virtualbox, virtualization

I have downloaded ubuntu 20.04 by following [these](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/install-ubuntu-desktop#1-overview) steps. I tried running it on VirtualBox, but the screen is either just showing the desktop or, if I try to resize the window, it turns black and doesn't come back.

[image]

I tried re-installing it, changing the amount of memory it is allowed to use, and other suggestions I found from other questions, like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1233157/ubuntu-20-04-lag-issues) and [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1349671/ubuntu-20-04-lagging-and-behaving-badly-after-i-halted-an-update-midway-also-i), on here, but nothing seems to work.

Some suggest that I run commands in the terminal in Ubuntu, but I can't do that when I don't see what's on the screen. I can't find the desktop icons or the sidebar menu. How can I fix this?

Comment: You tagged this question WSL. Are you actually using WSL, or you are just trying to install regular Ubuntu in a VM?

Comment: I am just trying to install regular ubuntu on VM.

Comment: Did you manage to install it at all? Or do you have problem running the live image for installation?

Comment: I've installed it sucessfully several times, each time I get the same issue...

Comment: Just a failure to start snap daemon should not cause a blank screen IMHO... Ubuntu can work perfectly well without the snap daemon (only you won't be able to run snap applications, but there are virtually none installed by default in Ubuntu 20.04 except the Snap Store). It looks strange why it doesn't display properly if the live system displays properly during installation... The live system is there exactly to try if the installed one will work...

Comment: Look at the "preview" window in your screenshot: It's not blank/black. It seems to be showing a problem with your VM video settings. Try fiddling with the amount of video memory.

Comment: I have tried setting them to to the minimum/maximum capacity, it doesn't seem to make a difference. I thought it mighave to do with the amount of memory, buhen I tried to make it with increased memory the screen is still 'lagging' and/or turning black

Comment: Try to modify your video driver. Here's a [link](https://carleton.ca/scs/2019/virtualbox-graphics-controller-vmsvga-settings/) to VirtualBox and their recommendations.

Comment: My settings on the Display page: VMSVGA Graphics Controller, 128 MB, 1 monitor, min scale factor, acceleration off. Works for me. https://i.imgur.com/Pnp7w11.png